# ExtJS - Drop down menu that open up upward

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've created a drop down menu with ExtJS and everything working fine as expected. But I want it to be "drop-up" not drop-down since the menu bar will be laying out at the bottom of the viewport. I can't figure out what to add or change to make it "drop-up," help please.

**Program Code:-**

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Split', {
            text: 'Split Button',
            handler: onButtonClick,
            iconCls: 'start-up-icon',
            menu : {
                items: [{
                    text: '<b>Menu1</b>', handler: onItemClick
                }, {
                    text: '<b>Menu2</b>', handler: onItemClick
                }, {
                    text: '<b>Menu3</b>', handler: onItemClick
                }]
                }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `menuAlign` config.

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Split', {
    text: 'Split Button',
    menuAlign: 'bl-tl',
    menu: {
        items: [{
            text: '<b>Menu1</b>'
        }]
    }
});
```

[Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-menuAlign)

Comment: Wow,amazing Evan! This is what actually i'm looking for, you made my day :) Thanks for that!

Comment: Evan - One more question, is it possible to load the these menus from Store just like Trees?